# How to hide an element when a radio button is checked using Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I'm currently trying to use `click` and `ngIf*`to do this, but the change only happens if I double click. Also, if I double click the currently selected option, the view will change and I don't want that to happen. How can I do this properly?

```
      <fieldset class="form-group col-md-3">
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input (click)="computation = !computation" type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
          Enable View
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input (click)="computation = !computation" type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
          Disable View
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div *ngIf="computation" class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="app_id_org_input">Enabled</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="app_id_org_input" placeholder="Enabled">
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!computation" class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="app_id_input">Disabled</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="app_id_input" placeholder="Disabled">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another approach for you to achieve this. You can make use of the ngModel to let the Angular2 change the variable value. Here is the code that works for me.
In your class,

```
// set your variable
private computation = true;
```

In your template,

```
  <fieldset class="form-group col-md-3">
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" [value]="true" checked [(ngModel)]="computation">
          Enable View
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" [value]="false" [(ngModel)]="computation">
          Disable View
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div *ngIf="computation" class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="app_id_org_input">Enabled</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="app_id_org_input" placeholder="Enabled">
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!computation" class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="app_id_input">Disabled</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="app_id_input" placeholder="Disabled">
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where should I declare the variable computation. Does this error have to do with that? Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

Comment: You should import the FormsModule into your module first. Then, declare computation in your component class. I think you have already declared, or the original one will not work.